# Parsing JSON for consumption in highchart.js

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I'm pulling multiple values from a DB and doing calculations on them in a servlet and passing the values as a response back to my front end which then uses `highchart.js` to visualize the data.

Currently I creating a string in the form of a JSON object that highchart can consume, But I'd like to refine my code by using a libaray like GSON or Jackson
obviously this will be less error prone and more reusable, but I'm unsure if i can do it.

My current parsing method:

```
        this.json = "[";
        this.zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin");
        this.map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.dayCount = 0;
        this.end = "[" + (to.toInstant().getEpochSecond() * TimestampUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND + "," + null + "]]}");

public String Generate(String type) {

    // Check that we have dates to work with
    if (sDate != null && eDate != null) {

        // Pull data from DB
        try {
            throughPutList = dbWork.getThroughputEntriesInTimespan(env, app, from, to, connection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] calculations = new String[]{"default", "total"};

        assert throughPutList != null;
        int count = 1;
        for (String calc : calculations) {
            for (ThroughputEntry chartModel : throughPutList) {

                // Convert the epochSecond value of the period pulled for the DB to it's day for insertion into a Map
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(chartModel.getRetrieved(), zoneId);
                LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
                entryDay = localDate.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toEpochSecond() * TimestampUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND;
                valueForDate = map.get(entryDay);

                if (count == 1) {
                    json += "{\"name\": \"" + calc + "\", \"data\":[[" + (from.toInstant().getEpochSecond() * TimestampUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND + "," + null + "],");
                }
                if (calc.equals("default")) {
                    Default(chartModel);
                } else if (calc.equals("total")) {
                    Total(chartModel);
                } 
                if (count == throughPutList.size()) {

                    for (Map.Entry<Long, BigDecimal> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                        json += "[" + (entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue() + "],");
                    }
                    if (calc != "total") {
                            json += end + ",";

                    } else {
                            json += end;
                    }

                    map.clear();
                    count = 0;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        json += "]";

        if (throughPutList == null) {
            json = "No record found";
        }
    } else {
        json = "Date must be selected." + "App : " + app + " " + eDate;
    }
    return json;
}

public void Default(ThroughputEntry chartModel) {

    map.put(chartModel.getRetrieved().getEpochSecond() * TimestampUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND, BigDecimal.valueOf(chartModel.getThroughput()));
}

public void Total(ThroughputEntry chartModel) {

    newTotalForDate = (null == valueForDate) ? BigDecimal.valueOf(chartModel.getThroughput()) :
            valueForDate.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(chartModel.getThroughput()));

    if (null == newTotalForDate) {  // If we failed to get new value.
        // TODO: Handle error condition.
    } else {  // Else normal, we have a new total. Store it in map.

        map.put(entryDay, newTotalForDate);  // Replaces any old value.s
    }
}
```

So the The library will need to populate the JSON response using `String` values and a `linkedHashMap`

The response JSON needs to be of this form:

```
[{"name": "mean", "data":[[1454806080000,null],[1454889600000,204.043],[1454976000000,202.281],[1455062400000,160.493],[1455148800000,206.000],[1455235200000,229.917],[1455321600000,82.430],[1455408000000,87.242],[1455494400000,223.584],[1455580800000,188.412],[1455667200000,228.199],[1455753600000,224.268],[1455840000000,198.513],[1455842880000,null]]},{"name": "extrapo", "data":[[1454806080000,null],[1455842880000,null]]},{"name": "max", "data":[[1454806080000,null],[1455842880000,null]]}]
```

The response in practice will have much more data in it ~126 sets.

I'm consuming this clients side:

```
// Function for loading data via AJAX and showing it on the chart
function ajaxLoadChart(startDate, endDate, appName, envName) {
    // If no data is passed (the chart was cleared)
    if (!startDate || !endDate) {
        return;
    }
    // Otherwise, issue an AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myServlet.com/operations.PreProcessor',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            start: startDate,
            end: endDate,
            env: envName,
            app: appName
        },
        success: function (json) {

            options.series[0] = json[0];
            options.series[1] = json[1];
            options.series[2] = json[2];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + " " + error);
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    })
}
```

Is it possible to use one of the mentioned libraries to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to achieve and have done something similar myself.

The thing to do is create some POJOS (Plain Ol' Java Oblects) which represent the data structure you are currently creating in JSON. These should have all the same member names, children, etc. as your current JSON structure. You then build that up then pass it to GSON to be serialized as JSON.

I've done this and call the objects I've created my 'View Model' which is then passed the the client as a JSON string.